How to show a custom crash report window in AvaloniaUI?
I have an AvaloniaUI application. I have created a simple Window that I want to show to my users on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.
The issue is that showing the window needs to somehow stop the thread where the Exception was thrown (similar to winforms MessageBox). This could be achieved by using ShowDialog IF there was a visible parent window. But I can't ensure that. If I simply show the window, the application just goes down and the window disappears immediately.
What's the common approach here? Do I create a separate CrashReporter executable that I launch? I really only care about displaying information to the user in a somewhat nice way. Can I achieve similar behavior to MessageBox.Show?

Avalonia currently doesn't have a MessageBox type control.  This is likely due to the fact it would be useless on mobile, because mobile OSes don't support the concept of a window. This is the same reason ShowDialog requires a Window in Avalonia, where it is optional in UI like WPF.  That said, the devs have said they are considering adding it for Desktop contexts.
As far as strategy, have you considered storing the error in persistence and showing it to the user on the next launch?  This relies on the fact that if an app suddenly dies, the user is likely to launch it again. At that point, before anything else happens, you could show an informational window or ask them to send you a report of the problem.
